# How do I increase the number of threads that process the full text index in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am processing a full text index of a table that contains 25 million rows and would like to speed it up. According to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175787(v=sql.80).aspx) article (point #5) it is possible in the full version of SQL Server by editing some registry keys:

> Increase the number of threads for the indexing process
> Increase the number of threads you're running for the indexing
> process. The default is only five, and on quads or 8-ways, you can
> bump this up to much higher values. MSSearch will, however, throttle
> itself if it's slurping too much data from SQL Server, so avoid doing
> this on single- or dual-processor systems.
>
> These are the relevant Registry entries:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Search\1.0\ Gathering
> Manager\Servers\SQLServer\EvaluationOrder
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Search\1.0\ Gathering
> Manager\Servers\SQLServer\HitInterval

Of course we don't have access to the registry in Azure SQL Database, is there another way? Maybe by executing a system query?

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubts if the quoted registry settings relate to SQL Server FTI (Full-text Indexing) number of threads. The key location itself relates to MSSearch (which is an application that uses FTI), the article itself does not explain what values should be used and the names of the keys do not really seems to correspond to threads. Last but not least they are not officially documented and the article is from June 2004.

The [Improve the Performance of Full-Text Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/improve-the-performance-of-full-text-indexes) has more relevant information. The sp_configure 'max full-text crawl range' can be used to allocate all CPU processors or cores to FTI. However this option is not yet available on Azure, unlike for example the option to specify the [maximum degree of parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql) for SQL Server. However, the mentioned perforce article might provide alternative methods to suit your needs.